# Android - add menu item to Android's built-in apps

Tags: android

i want to add a button or menu item  in the Contacts menu . Is it possible.???
Im using Android 2.2 and Eclipse 3.6.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The built-in Android apps do not support intent options in their menus, i.e. you cannot add anything to them.

Comment: Can i add a new menu to the Option menu of Contacts of Android emulator

Comment: Not unless you take the source code of the contacts app, modify it and rebuild it as a new app.