# Can we add some menu item to the Android's native Menu

Tags: android

I want to add a task of my application in the android native menu.
Suppose if my app is for creating notes I want to provide a "add new note" 
menu item here in the default menu of android.

Is it possible to do so. If yes then how?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this is yet not possible in Android for any application to register its menu item on system level also aou may look at following post [Android - add menu item to Android's built-in apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487055/android-add-menu-item-to-androids-built-in-apps)

Comment: thanks Man, I think Google Should provide some feature of this type in future releases.